# Assignment gives unexpected answer

Tags: java

Today I've encountered the following problem, to which I can't seem to find a solution:

```
int i, j, k;

i = j = k = 3;

i = k++;
```

So it seemed logical to me that the variable 'i' must have the value 4 now, since we assigned the increment of 'k' to it. In the multiple choice test, the correct values after the third line were instead:

```
k = 4
```

and

```
i != 4
```

Since we assigned the increment of k to i, how come the given solution is the exact opposite to what I had expected?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between `++k` and `k++`?

Comment: Don't, ever, use i = k++. This is asking for bugs. Use `k++; i = k;` or `i = k; k++;`. That can't be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Firstly, as noted by JB Nizet, **don't do this**. Very occasionally I'll use a postfix increment within another expression, for thing likes `array[index++] = value;` but very often I'll pull it out into two statements for clarity.

---

I wasn't going to answer this question, but *all* the answers (at the time of posting) make the same mistake: this isn't a matter of *timing* at all; it's a matter of the value of the expression `k++`.

The assignment to `i` happens *after* the increment of `k` - but the value of the expression `k++` is the original value of `k`, not the incremented value.

So this code:

```
i = k++;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
int tmp = k;
k++;
i = tmp;
```

From [section 15.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) (emphasis mine):

> [...] Otherwise, the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable. Before the addition, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable. If necessary, the sum is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3) and/or subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to the type of the variable before it is stored. **The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable before the new value is stored.**

This difference is very important, and can easily be seen if instead of using the postfix expression for an assignment, you call a method:

```
public class Test {

    private static int k = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        foo(k++);
    }

    private static void foo(int x) {
        System.out.println("Value of parameter: " + x);
        System.out.println("Value of k: " + k);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Value of parameter: 0
Value of k: 1
```

As you can see, `k` has *already been incremented* by the time we call the method, but the value passed into the method is still the original value.

Comment: Thanks alot. So if instead, we had the expression i = ++k, int tmp would be assigned the value of the already incremented k, so i would receive the value 4 for 'i' and for 'k'?

Comment: @JohannaN.-A.: Yes, exactly.